# Create rules from text Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this written sentence:

> John is a footballer. Mary is an actress. All of Mary's friends are
> footballers and are blond (*their hair*). All of John's friends are
> footballers or actors.

How could i create Prolog rules for last two sentences?
This is what i have for now:

```
footballer(john).
actor(Mary).
color(blond)  # not sure if its ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
footballer(john).
footballer(joe).

actor(mary).
actor(kevinbacon).

singer(elvis).

cosmonaut(yuri).

friend(john, X) :- footballer(X).
friend(john, X) :- actor(X).
```

See that asking `?- friend(john, F).` finds joe, mary and kevinbacon, and does not find elvis or yuri.

You can do a similar thing for `friend(mary, X)` and `blonde_hair(marilyn)`.

You may need to work out how to say that John is not friends with himself, perhaps using [dif/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif%2f2).

---

This approach is quite simple and you can ask "who is a footballer?" but you cannot easily ask "what does John do?". For that you might consider:

```
person_job(john, footballer).
person_job(ronaldo, footballer).

person_job(mary, actress).
person_job(elvis, singer).

person_haircolour(elvis, black).
person_haircolour(sia, blonde).
```

and building on those relations (relating a person to their job, a person to their hair colour) will let you ask "who is a footballer?" as well as "what does John do?" or "who has blonde hair?".

(All John's friends are footballers, but are all thousands and thousands of footballers friends with John?)

(Is it a trick prompt, Mary is an *actress*, John is friends with *actors*?)